# Selenium Webdriver : How to delete an open email from Gmail using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gmail

Code that i have tried :

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Delete' and @role = 'button']"));
```

and

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("///div[@class='iH bzn']//div[@aria-label='Delete' and @role = 'button']"));
```

This path is not accepted by selenium while running the code.
I have tried Mouse hover as well but its not working for me.
Anybody can help me with this?
Please find the attached image

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**If someone can help with java script to delete email , it would be also helpful**

Comment: Just delete mails through API.

Comment: Can you Try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-tooltip=\"Delete\"]")).click();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need `Mouse hover` to `groupElement`:

```
//div[@class='iH bzn']//div[@class='G-tF']//div[2][@class='G-Ni G-aE J-J5-Ji']
```

[image: groupElement]

The delete icon need trigger from another element to visible:

```
//add some wait here
WebElement groupElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='iH bzn']//div[@class='G-tF']//div[2][@class='G-Ni G-aE J-J5-Ji']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(groupElement).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Delete']//div[@class='asa']")).click();
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Comment: As OP asked how to use `selenium` to accomplish the task this is a good answer! (altho, it can be accomplished via API or JS)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript code which through you can delete open email from Gmail.

```
let down = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
let up = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('nX')[0];
elem.dispatchEvent(down);
elem.dispatchEvent(up);
```

Thanks.